# How do I install libomp package in amazon linux 2 or centos 7?

Tags: centos, software-installation, amazon-linux

I have been trying to install a software we require called snapgene_viewer, it seems to fail requiring libomp,

```
Error: Package: snapgene-viewer-6.1-2.x86_64 (/snapgene_viewer_6.1.2_linux)
           Requires: libomp
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I even tried installing via `homebrew` `https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/libomp` since there was a direct package of it, that also fails with,

```
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/xz-20221129-23304-127j8iw/xz-5.2.7':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

But I do have gcc installed on the machine,
Here the output of `gcc -v`

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/7/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --enable-bootstrap --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada,go,lto --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --enable-multilib --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-gcc-major-version-only --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --with-isl --enable-libmpx --enable-libsanitizer --enable-gnu-indirect-function --enable-libcilkrts --enable-libatomic --enable-libquadmath --enable-libitm --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-15) (GCC)
```

Learning the difference between llvm and gcc, also installed llvm toolset, since `yum search libomp`, pointed me to libraries containing it, like,

```
llvm-toolset-7-libomp.x86_64 : OpenMP runtime for clang
llvm-toolset-7-libomp-devel.x86_64 : OpenMP header files
llvm-toolset-7.0-libomp.x86_64 : OpenMP runtime for clang
llvm-toolset-7.0-libomp-devel.x86_64 : OpenMP header files
llvm-toolset-7.0-libomp-test.x86_64 : OpenMP regression tests
```

`libomp` was a part of it and installed under `/opt`, I made sure they are available under `/usr/lib` via symlink,

Still, no difference as such.

What am I missing, how do I get this working?